# install4j Multiplatform Edition Question

Tags: java, installation, multiplatform

I'm interested in cross-platform capabilities of the above tool. Has anyone used it? Does it allow creating installers for different platforms directly under Windows, or I have to install Mac and Linux versions separately in order to build installers for those systems?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from their customer support:

> Yes, with the Multi-Platform Edition
>   you can create installers for Windows,
>   Mac OS X and Unix on any platform.

Looks good so far.

Answer (score 0):

Another commercial alternative, if for whatever reason install4j does not work for you is [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) (disclaimer, I am the author). It is also capable of producing installation packages for Windows, OS X and Linux